# CardView animation issue: no initial animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

There are two `CardView`s is in a `RecyclerView` in a `FrameLayout`. One `CardView` has an  `android:visibility="gone"` setting on it. When tapped, the card flips 360 degrees, revealing the 'gone' `CardView`. Tapping it again flips it, showing the initial card. This sounds simple now.

Used the `ObjectAnimator` class to do this, like so:

```
public static void flipView(View viewToFlip, int direction)
{
    ObjectAnimator flipAnimator;

    if (direction == CLOCKWISE)
    {
        flipAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToFlip, "rotationY", 0f, 360f);
        flipAnimator.setDuration(3500);
        flipAnimator.start();
    }
    else
    {
        flipAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToFlip, "rotationY", 360f, 0f);
        flipAnimator.setDuration(3500);
        flipAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

The issue is that when the `CardView` shows up *initially*, the animation ***does not*** work, as in there is no flip. The card just gets replaced with the 'gone' card sans any animation. Only on subsequent taps, the animation works beautifully. My questions are:

- Why does the animation not work from the word go? (In the title of the question, 'initial' means 'on the first tap on the `CardView`' when it shows up in the `Fragment`)
- What is the fix?

Please let me know if you need to examine more code.

Thank you for your expert advice!

Comment: I suggest you to wrap Animation inside CountDownTimer with no delay

Comment: @MicheleLacorte, thanks for looking in and the advice. Modified the method like this: 

    `...
        final ObjectAnimator flipAnimator;

        if (direction == CLOCKWISE)
        {
            flipAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToFlip, "rotationY", 0f, 360f);
            new CountDownTimer(3000,3000)
            {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                {
                    flipAnimator.start();
                } ...
   }.start(); ...`

Still missing something, as the result is the same. More light please? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the bad code formatting